# PHP navigation with $_GET method ignoring css active class

Tags: php, css, navigation

My hover links work as well as the navigation, but the active link will not come on.

My CSS active:

```
#header ul li a.active,
#header ul li a.active:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
```

Here is my nav.php file:

```
<ul>
<?php
$pages = array(
    "index.php?p=home" => "Home", 
    "index.php?p=contact" => "Contact Us", 
    "index.php?p=services" => "Services", 
    "index.php?p=employees" => "Employees", 
    "index.php?p=dashboard" => "Dashboard");

$p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';

  if (preg_match("/$p/",$url)) {  
        echo "class='active'";                              
   }                                                      
  echo '><a href=', "$url", '>', "$label", '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

This is my method inside of the index page retrieving each page:

```
<?php
  if (file_exists("pages/$p.php")) {
    include("pages/$p.php");
}else{
include("pages/home.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using urls like: `/index.php?p=page_name`

```
<ul>
<?php
$pages = array(
    "home" => "Home", 
    "contact" => "Contact Us", 
    "services" => "Services", 
    "employees" => "Employees", 
    "dashboard" => "Dashboard");

$p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';

  if ($p == $url) {  
        echo "class='active'";                              
   }                                                      
  echo '><a href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $label . '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the index.php that worked fine but the links still wont go active. the active class needs to be on the <li> and on the <a> if that makes a difference.

Comment: this is my css maybe something is wrong with it? #header ul li a.active,
#header ul li a.active:hover {
 color:#fff;
 background:#000;
 font-weight:bold;

Comment: if ($p == $url) {  
        echo echo '<li><a class="active" href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $label . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo echo '<li><a href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $label . '</a></li>';
    }

Comment: that broke my code :/

Comment: Sorry, "echo echo" syntax :-) Try: if ($p == $url) { echo '<li><a class="active" href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $label . '</a></li>'; } else { echo '<li><a href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $label . '</a></li>'; }